# Chi-square, p-value and political elections

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics, contingency-tables

I am looking at which category is mostly associated with people who voted.
A sample of results from my dataset is as follows

```
(Yes, Right) : xxx people
(No, Right) : xx people
(NA, Left): xxx people
(Yes, Left): xxx people
(No, Left): xx people
(Yes, Center): xxx people
(No, Center): xxx people
```

where xx and xxx are the number of people in each category. NA means not available.  Calculating the chi squared, I have found the following values:

```
Chi-squared: 569.74 p-value: 2.66e-94
```

This was calculated as follows: `stat, p = chi2_contingency(df)` using scipy.

However I do not know how I could explain at a high level within this context (i.e., voters and political parties). Has someone any experience in explaining statistical test to a technical (and very experienced) audience?

Comment: Do you only have three categories and three type of votes? To explain the high level a simple diagram could already explain the differences in voting behaviour of those three categories.

Comment: Is your question about explaining the test or about explaining the data? Does your audience care about the chi-squared test?

Comment: Hi Sextus Empiricus, my audience should include both high technical and business people. My question is more about explaining the data and results, but I guess that business audience will care also to understand about the chi-squared test

Comment: DId you try to use a diagram or table, and if so why did it not work?